# Como liberar um nível de URL e Query String com barra ou sem via .htaccess e nos demais ter um erro 404?

Tags: htaccess, url-amigável, querystring

Com .htaccess preciso liberar um nivel de url de bloquear os demais com erro 404 sendo:

/exemplo (pode)

/exemplo/ (pode)

/exemplo/**qualquer_coisa** (**não pode**)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d



RewriteRule (^.*)$ index.php?piada=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Meu código atual ou deixar passar tudo depois da barra, ou só funciona com a barra. Sou péssimo com .htaccess podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido com o seguinte código:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.[a-z0-9-]+/?)$ index.php?piada=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```